# Django Rest Framework Paging

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to make my API get return a maximum of 10 per page. This helps me with infinite loading. The API url will be I am trying looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/api/test/?user=5&page=1
```

However, this does not work.

I've followed the official [docs here without](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) success.

I have only modified two files, settings.py & rest_views.py.

settings.py-

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'
}
```

rest_views.py-

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

...

wardrobematch = {
    'user': lambda x: ('user__pk', x)  
}

class WardrobeListView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    paginate_by = 10
    paginate_by_param = 'page_size'
    max_paginate_by = 100

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in wardrobematch:
                lookup, val = wardrobematch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Analytic.objects
            .filter(like=True,**filters)
            .order_by('-updated',)
            # .distinct('product_id',)
            .values('product_id', 'product__name', 'product__brand', 'product__store__store_name', 'product__variation__image__image', 'product__variation__price__price',)
        )

        return Response(qset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your first example working- to me it was clearer and more basic. All I did was add ".object_list" to stop the "is not JSON serializable" error.

This is your answer with my tiny tweak:

```
class WardrobeListView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in wardrobematch:
                lookup, val = wardrobematch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Analytic.objects
            .filter(like=True,**filters)
            .order_by('-updated',)
            # .distinct('product_id',)
            .values('product_id', 'product__name', 'product__brand', 'product__store__store_name', 'product__variation__image__image', 'product__variation__price__price',)
    )
        paginator = Paginator(qset, 2) # Show 25 items per page

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            qset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
             # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            qset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
             # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            qset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return Response(qset.object_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using regular ApiView, you should call the pagination API yourself, it will not perform pagination automatically.

I have created a pagination and a serializer mixim. I'm not sure it is best method, but it worked for me.

```
class SerializerMixim(object):

    def serialize_object(self,obj):
        """Serilize only needed fields"""
        return NotImplementedError


class PaginationMixim(object):

    _serializer = None

    def paginate(self,queryset,num=10):
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, num)
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        count = paginator.count
        previous = None if not queryset.has_previous() else queryset.previous_page_number()
        next = None if not queryset.has_next() else queryset.next_page_number()
        if self._serializer:
            objects = self._serializer(queryset.object_list,many=True).data
        else:
            objects = [self.serialize_object(i) for i in queryset.object_list]

        data = {'count':count,'previous':previous,
                 'next':next,'object_list':objects}
        return Response(data)

    def serialize_object(self,obj):
        return {'id':obj.pk}


class WardrobeListView(APIView,PaginationMixim,SerializerMixim):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    #_serializer = AnalyticSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in wardrobematch:
                lookup, val = wardrobematch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Analytic.objects
            .filter(like=True,**filters)
            .order_by('-updated',)
            # .distinct('product_id',)


        return self.paginate(qset)

    def serialize_object(self,obj):
        return obj.serilized
```

then you need to create a propery for Analytic model like,

```
class Analytic(models.Model):
    .....

    @property
    def serilized(self):

        summary = {
            'id':self.product.id,
            'image':self.product.name,
            .......
        }
        return summary
```

this will also work with django rest serializers

Comment: Ah I see- this answer gives me type error (<Page 1 of 146> is not JSON serializable). I did not have one before. Can you advise?

Comment: Thanks- but something isn't communicating from AnalyitcSerializer as I keep getting field errors (eg Field name `product_id` is not valid for model `Analytic`)

Comment: Can you share you models.py

Comment: Your answer is not working for me. It tells me "return self.paginate(qset)" is a SyntaxError. Also, with the part I add to my "models.py", should I still use lookups (like product_name or product__variation__image__image)? In your example, you used a "."

Comment: See my edit I missed to add SerializerMixim.No you don't need to use lookup

Comment: I am still getting a syntax error for "return self.paginate(qset)". Also, where do I define the values I need included in the API result?